# How to set a string name for pipeline build in jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I am running jenkins on a linux machine.
I have a pipeline job in place, so each pipeline build shows build number in general. Instead of that is it possible to give string parameter to display on the UI ?
I have tried checking build parameter plugin, but in pipeline configuration i don't see option to inject the string parameter. And the documentation doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the build name by doing:

```
currentBuild.displayName = "#${currentBuild.number} Hello"
```

This will name the build `#2 Hello` for build number 2.

Comment: Does it should be in the groovy script ? And in case via pipeline i trigger n number of builds so does it take different names as it changes in the parameter ?

Comment: i trigger this pipeline job from another Job-a.
job-a has a set of values, each value it would generate a parameter and for each parameter the pipeline build starts

Comment: Yes, you put this in your pipeline groovy script, and you can reference any variable that you have available in ordinary pipeline script..

Comment: Nice one. You just forgot the dollar sign before the variable `#${currentBuild.number}`

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i had to add a line in my pipeline groovy script

```
node(Slave01) {
currentBuild.displayName = "${URL_Name}"
}
```

${URL_Name} = here is the parameter